# SSRS - Sort report with drill-down rows

Tags: reporting-services

I'm setting the interactive-sort property in a cell, and in normal reports this lets me click to sort the rows.

I now have a report with multiple groups/drill-down rows, and the interactive sort doesn't seem to do anything. The rows stay in the same order.

Anybody had issues with this? Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Report Builder 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9f783224-9871-4eea-b1d5-f3140a253db6&displaylang=en), right-click the column you're interested in, select Text Box properties, select Interactive Sorting from the left, and under "Choose what to sort" change from "Detail rows" to "Groups".

Comment: what version of ssrs are you using? We're using 2005 and I don't see what you are talking about.

Comment: I'm using SSRS 2008, but the application I'm using to edit my reports in Report Builder 2.0. I'll update the post.